# Is there a way to determine which string shows up the most within a certain row?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm setting up a database, and this database has several reviews. I am wanting to select a review, and I am wanting to identify the word that occurs the most within this review.  For example, lets say a review is "terrible food, terrible service, bad place."  I want to return the word terrible. I am running on **Oracle 11g Express**.

I am actually completely stumped on this. I would know how to do it if the rows just contained one string, but since the rows contain several strings (full paragraphs), this is proving to be an issue for me.  I am using PL/SQl, so I am not limited to just SQL statements.

**Here is my review table**

```
CREATE TABLE REVIEW (
review_id INT,
review_text CLOB,
primary key (review_id));
```

As I said, I am pretty stumped on this.  I can't find too much information on how to sort through a large line of text, and then find the most common string that occurs within the text.

Comment: See https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:9536872200346063885

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things to handle like words such as "Terrible food, terrible service, bad place." Should "Terrible" and "terrible" be counted together also removal of punctuation. These can be handled by regular expressions. Also, if several words have the same count should each be shown. The following answers this a positive.

```
with review as
      -- CTE (Oracle: Subquery Factoring) for test data. TO BE Replaced by actual table.
     (select 'Terrible food, terrible service, bad, bad place' || chr(13) || chr(10) || 'Just stay away!!' review_text from dual)
   , review_words as
     -- Strip target string of Punctuation and Control characters, also reduce multiple spaces to single space
     (select regexp_replace(regexp_replace(review_text,'[[:punct:][:cntrl:]]',' '),'\s{2,}',' ') rwords
        from review
     )
   , word_list as 
     -- Now from result of above the individual words and convert to lower case.
     ( select lower(regexp_substr(rwords,'[^ ]+',1,rownum)) words 
         from review_words connect by level <=  regexp_count(rwords,' ') 
     )
-- get each word and count highest ranked words.
select word, cnt 
  from ( -- Rank the Word count  
         select word, cnt, rank() over(order by cnt desc) rnk
           from (-- get the number of occurrence of eah word.
                 select words word, count(*) cnt 
                   from word_list   
                  group by words
                )
       )
 where rnk = 1;
```

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ecd9bcc94287f3ca5301d8c0ce6e18ef) here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will help...
I have found this [ARTICLE](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/asktom.search?tag=ora-00838-specified-value-of-memory-target-is-too-small)

And I have reconfigured  it just a little bit so it finds a most common email in the clob column. Here is the query :

```
with emails as (
  select 
    cast(trim(
      regexp_substr(t.toaddress, '[^,]+', 1, levels.column_value)
    ) as varchar2(320)) as email,
    domain,
    id
  from  t,
        table(cast(multiset(
          select level from dual 
          connect by level <= length (regexp_replace(t.toaddress, '[^,]+')) + 1
        ) as sys.OdciNumberList)) levels
)
  select email from (select email, count(email) ce
  from   emails
  group by email) where ce = (select max(ce) 
                              from (select email, count(email) ce
                                    from   emails
                                    group by email));
```

And here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8f58c3328dc9edba5bcef50186303f83)
But all the **glory goes to** **Connor McDonald**